# Prolog, List with key mecanism

Tags: prolog

Good morning! I would like to solve this problem, i'm lost.
I have these data

```
ing(salt).
ing(egg).
ing(oil).
ing(water).

food(pa, [salt,egg,oil]).
food(he, [salt,egg,water]).
```

how can I find the food if for example the given ingredients are like this: [salt,oil], so the result must be the food >> 'pa'
Something like:

```
foodOf([salt,oil]):- ...
//must return the food in general not only the *string* 'pa'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it!

```
list(E,[E|_]).
list(E,[_|L]) :- list(E,L).

inclus([],_).
inclus([E|L1],L2):-list(E,L2),inclus(L1,L2).

foodof(F,X):- food(F,Y),inclus(X,Y).
```

it works perfectly, sorry if i took times to solve it!